# I cannot seem to get my worker pool to stop properly on terminate signal

Tags: go

I'm trying to follow this tutorial/example here to setup my beanstalkd workers:

https://github.com/pjebs/beanstalkd-worker

My goal is to create a running go program that should listen to several beanstalkd tubes at once, and attempt to spawn workers on demand (and on available resources such as CPU, Memory etc). The workers actually simply a wrapper call for external workers (php, python, etc) to do certain jobs and catch back the returns.

The current issue is that when I try to run this program with go run test.go then the program would get stuck forever. It seems like I have made some mistake that cause my program to miss several wg.Done() that it should have called. I just cannot figure out where.

https://gist.github.com/yellow1912/afbd181a3dc2919f439d

(I'm a very beginner in Go, please feel free to criticize my code and suggest ways to improve)

Comment: This isn't the place for codereview, but you need to clean up some stuff and make this so it can compile first. Even better would be to create an example that we can run to see your problem without the external dependencies. You don't need to dereference `wg`. Don't call `wc.Done()` in multiple places or you'll panic, just defer it once. You have a loop over an undefined `c`, which will never end unless you close `c`, so nothing in the goroutine will ever execute. You have a data race on the `signalReceived` variable.

Comment: As @JimB said, this isn't a place for large code reviews - create and Issue for the library/package you are using. Here on SO, you need to narrow down to the section of code you have a question about, about 10 to 20 lines of code maybe and post it here in the question. Else, this topic can be closed.

Comment: Thank you all. I have cleaned up my code thanks to your suggestion and then tried to run again and got passed the error I had earlier. I still struggle to see how to handle "deadline soon" for beanstalkd but that is an entirely different issue. Please help me to close this and thank you again for your help pointing out some obvious issues I missed.